# JSON Parsing in Javascript & node

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am trying to parse a JSON Array that I posted from the client side to a node based server.

the json object holding the array looks like this

```
customData : {
    "playlist": [
        "//www.youtube.com/embed/bxq6SofU_38?rel=0",
        "//www.youtube.com/embed/Qyqchamz4EM?rel=0"
    ]
}
```

However when I try to access the data using customData.playlist[0], it returns that it cannot parse 'playlist' the console reports that it is undefined.

I checked my JSON using the JSONLint validator and it said that me JSON was valid. I must be missing something  pretty simple any thoughts?

Comment: customData should be a variable. Then you can call `customData.playlist`: `var customData = yourJsonObject`

Comment: Could you post your actual JSON, not something that looks like it? The snippet you posted isn't valid JSON for example, since customData isn't in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

if you get data from client side you should parse that like this:

```
var parsed = JSON.parse(recievedData);
```

and then you have access them.

Comment: As Super Hornet points out, you need to parse it as when you receive data from a request it's a string usually. 

When parsing be sure to wrap it in try/catch as a client could send a random invalid JSON string which causes an exception in JSON.parse. I made this module to deal with safely parsing JSON https://www.npmjs.org/package/safejson

Answer (score 0):

Whenever response comes from a server or client ,the result will be in string.. Coz you know strings are easier to transfer within networks... Try to use JSON.parse.   console the typeof of customData .. It must be object.. Then only you can.. Get values..